# Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported Php

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, phpexcel

I am working with Php (Codeigniter) and i am tyring to use "excel" library in my project,I uploaded files and folders in "libraries" folder and use following code

```
public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();        
$this->load->library('excel');
$this->load->model('Crud_model');
}
```

But i am getting "Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported" error, How can i resolve this ? Thank You in advance.

Comment: Your PHP version is outdated.

Comment: @nice_dev are you sure ?

Comment: Looking at the _curly braces is no longer supported_, yes. What is your PHP version?

Comment: See https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_curly_braces_array_access#wasn_t_the_curly_brace_syntax_deprecated_once_before

Comment: @nice_dev current version is "7.4.29"

Comment: Makes sense then. The excel library you downloaded has that then. Does the error go away if you don't load the library? Which version of excel is it? Are you on windows?

Comment: @nice_dev yes i am on windows

Comment: ok, what about my other questions?

Comment: @Rick issue in not in here. comment these two `$this->load->library('excel');`
`$this->load->model('Crud_model');` and check enabling one by one.

Answer (score 3):

The code on your excel library is not support anymore with your current php version, you can downgrade php version or use the new excel library like PhpSpreadsheet